# Inquiry: Parse the following xml code with xml.etree?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml.etree

### Problem Statement:

Given the xml given below I want to write a simple script to produce **(http)www.herp.com/** and ***(http)www.herp.com/derp***. Conceivably for every application path I come across. That is, if I have more, such as: `<application path = "wassup" applicationPool="derp />`, I would want that too as **(http)www.herp.com/wassup**.

```
    <sites>
                        <site name="(http)www.herp.com" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">

                <application path="/" applicationPool="derp_administration">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\inetpub\herp_webs\derp" />
                    <virtualDirectory path="/Controls" physicalPath="D:\inetpub\usercontrolslibnew_ent" />
                </application>



                <application path="/derp" applicationPool="BOOGA">
                                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\inetpub\herp_webs\derp" />
                                <virtualDirectory path="/Controls" physicalPath="D:\inetpub\usercontrolslibnew" />
                </application>

              </site>
        </sites>
```

### Attempted Solution:

I am using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("applicationHost.config")
root = tree.getroot()

sites = root.iter('site')
for site in sites: 
    print site.get('name')
```

However, this obviously will only give me:

```
(http) www.herp.com
```

I am unable to see in the attributes anything that will point me to the `<application path = "i want this stuff" />`

I tried using site.tag, site.text, site.attrib, and site.tail and none of this helps me see the application path to build my url. How can I parse this xml code to give me both name and path attribute?

So given the excellent suggestions from here. I tried the following code:

```
sites = root.iter('site')
for site in sites: 
    apps = site.findall('application') 
    print apps.tag, apps.attrib
```

I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Similar error is given for tags. Basically, if I used `site.find('application')` that will give me the first `<application path ="/" applicationPool="whatever"/>`, but I cannot find the rest below it. I'm sorry. Apparently this particular config I ran it on had website dependencies that I was unaware of. I'm new on the job.

**Researched Sources**:

- RTFM: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
- http://luisartola.com/software/2010/easy-xml-in-python/
- google / here

**Notes:** 
I have multiple *.config files and parsing using a script is the way to go. I am aware of some GUI tools that can do basic stuff, but not appropriate here.

Comment: I added a closing `</site>` tag to the XML, and a closing parenthesis to `tree.getroot()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to obtain the `<application>` `Element` before you can access its `path` attribute. Given `site`, you can do this using `site.findall('application')`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("applicationHost.config")
root = tree.getroot()

sites = root.iter('site')
for site in sites: 
    apps = site.findall('application')
    for app in apps:
        print(''.join([site.get('name'), app.get('path')]))
```

prints

```
(http)www.herp.com/
(http)www.herp.com/derp
```

Comment: I updated my question to reflect some more details. I think I am almost there.

Comment: `findall()` returns a list of `Elements`. So use a `for-loop` to loop through the `Elements`.

Comment: I literally said 'duh' to myself when I read your response. An obvious detail I missed. Thanks for your gracious answer.